# Display a Graphics2D as JPG in JSP

Tags: java, swing, jsp, awt, graphics2d

Is it possible to use Graphics2D in a servlet?

And if I have a Graphics2D object, is it possible for me to convert it to a .jpg image and display it in a JSP page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion yes, [Read](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2000/jw-0505-servlets.html) the link for better understanding.

Comment: how do i use the JPEGImageEncoder? if I have to download the library do you have any idea where? can't seem to find it.

Comment: You can use Java Image IO [look here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) for API reference. you can easily read and write images.

Comment: you can also look at this [example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-return-an-image-from-a-servlet-using-imageio.html). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) has a good example of doing this. To accommodate older versions, it provides a [`org.jfree.chart.encoders.SunJPEGEncoderAdapter`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/encoders/SunJPEGEncoderAdapter.html). The [`encode()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/encoders/SunJPEGEncoderAdapter.html#line.127) method shows how to use [`ImageIO`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) for either byte array or stream.